# Reuse data flow from tMysqlInput

Tags: talend

I´ve a mysql statement which retrieves a **lot of data from** a table via the **tMysqlInput** component. Now I want to process the data in different ways and then merge them back again to a single output of the job.

Therefore I wanted to use the **tReplicate** component to avoid multiple requests to my SQL server. But if I´m using tReplicate I´m **not able to map the two datastreams afterwards again with tMap**.

Is there any other way to reuse the result of a mySql component multiple times?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tHashOutput to save the data from mysql and then use tHashInput to read that data and use in tMap.